# Probability of a number being rational vs. irrational

Tags: probability

If I throw a ball from a point (0 meters) and I know it will land at the most 1 meter away, what's the probability the distance from the initial point is rational and what's probability it's irrational?

This may sound like a stupid question but I'm really curious. Please don't roast me people.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming some reasonable, continuous distribution for the distance thrown, the distance will be rational with probability $0$, irrational with probability $1$. Given an interval $I = (a,b)$, with $a < b$, the measure of the subset of rationals in $I$ is $0$, and the measure of the subset of irrationals in $I$ is $b-a$.

Comment: Have you thought of how you would measure the distance covered by the ball to decide whether it is rational or irrational?

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi lol no it was just hypothetical

Comment: No need for roasting. That's a fundamental and pivotal question. The answer is the probability it is rational is 0 and irrational is 1 because there or infinitely more irrational then rational. Which is understandably confusing as it clearly shouldn't be impossible or certain. But equally confusing it is clear they can't logically have any other probabilities. Measure theory and prob. allowed for sets that have "no measure" but aren't empty. Meditate and study and it will eventually make sense.

Answer (score 5):

The formal way to answer this question is to use the [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) of the rationals.  The measure of any countable set, like the rationals is zero, so the probability of randomly selecting a rational is zero.  When we say that, you should not fall into the trap of assuming probability zero=can't happen, because it can.  It just won't.